# How to rewrite SEO URL in Magento?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, seo

I am working on FAQ custom module which lists all FAQ related with particular product.

The following is the my product view page link:

> http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/watches/titan-suprimo-501.html

And following is the my custom FAQ page link for this product:

> http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/faqmodule/product/list/id/1/category/3/

Now, my requirement is create above link SEO friendly respective with product like following:

> http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/watches/titan-suprimo-501/faqmodule.html
>   OR
>   http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/watches/titan-suprimo-501/faq.html

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to create your custom rewrite in admin.

Just go to url rewrite management and choose custom url rewrite type

Give unique id path in id path field

In request path give this http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/watches/titan-suprimo-501/faq.html
This is your request path from frontend

And in target path give this http://mydomain.com/magentoassignments/index.php/faqmodule/product/list/id/1/category/3/
internally magento use your target path.

And save your url rewrite

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply.